# How to write a two-line text in a Button label?

Tags: apache-flex, mxml

Is there a way, for a Button's "label" field, to display text over several lines? Or else to automatically "wrap" the text in several lines instead of cutting part of it?

Comment: Did you try "Line one\nLine two"

Comment: Yes I did. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible with the standard mx:Button - you can either create your own custom component to extend Button or look for others that have already created what you need.

For example the flexlib library contains a CanvasButton which would help:
http://flexlib.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/flexlib/controls/CanvasButton.html

Or if you prefer to do it yourself and create your own custom component this blog post will show you how:
http://www.forestandthetrees.com/2008/03/11/flex-multiline-button/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Flex 4, you could use this component:

**WrappingButton.as**

```
package 
{
  import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
  import mx.controls.Button;

  public class WrappingButton extends Button
  {

    public function WrappingButton()
    {
      super();
    }

    override protected function createChildren():void
    {
      super.createChildren();

      textField.multiline = true;
      textField.wordWrap = true;
      textField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
    }

    override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
    {
      super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
      textField.y = (this.height - textField.height) >> 1;

      height = textField.height + getStyle("paddingTop") + getStyle("paddingBottom");
      if (height < this.minHeight)
      {
        this.height = this.minHeight
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Flex 4 then use s:button and then make a custom Skin for it. Inside the Skin you will see